# Identify HTC 8X phone types

Tags: htc, htc-8x, display

I got a scratch on my phone and when I am going to buy a new display on ebay, there are few types of displays for this phone.

ex :- Full LCD Display +Touch Screen Digitizer Assembly For HTC 8X C625e C620e ADR6990

I tried lot find what my phone type is, but couldn't. Can anyone help me figure out what is the type.

Comment: What other examples have you found?

Comment: well this is one resource, mine one have radio and C620 has only radio on this web site http://pdadb.net/index.php?m=pdacomparer&id1=4031&id2=4039&id3=3889&id4=3816

and I finally called htc and they asked my IMIE and they told me exact version. it c620e :). I couldn't find any general way of find this.